# How to fix tab completion so it doesn't hide entries?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I'm using oh-my-zsh on Mac OS X with homebrew'ed zsh 4.3.12. I stumbled recently on a weird problem. In `scripts/not-used` I have several `.R` files:

```
breakdowns.R             eventloop.R              process-largeclients.R   process-qt.R
reprocess-pinning.R      calculate-qt-error.R     generate_decision_tree.R process-net.R
process-scalingexp.R
```

However, when I try `ls scripts/not-used/`+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the first completion is `ls scripts/not-used/_.R` where `_` represents cursor position. If I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, I get this weird completion:

```
$ ls scripts/not-used/.R                                                                          
breakdowns.R  eventloop.R
```

How to unset this ugly (wrong) behaviour?

The options that are set are:

```
alwaystoend autocd autonamedirs autopushd cdablevars completeinword
correctall extendedglob extendedhistory noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst histignoredups histignorespace histreduceblanks histverify
incappendhistory
interactive login longlistjobs monitor promptsubst 
pushdignoredups pushdminus pushdsilent pushdtohome
sharehistory shinstdin zle
```

Comment: how is `breakdowns.R eventloop.R` incorrect completion?  Try unsetting the `completeinword` option, as this allows completion to be done from both ends of the cursor, left and right.  That means, that if I type `pac` as in `pacman`, and there's a command called `arpac`, then `arpac` will be in the list of completions, since completion occurs on both sides of the cursor instead of only to the right.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the question... So, `breakdowns.R eventloop.R` is an incorrect completion, in the sense of incompleteness. If you look closely at the list of files, there are more than just those 2, ending with `.R`.

Comment: I tried touching into existence a bunch of files with the same names as the ones you listed as well as a z.R, a z,.R and a z_test.R for testing purposes - z_test.R wouldn't show up trying to autocomplete it, but z,.R would. Guessing it's some kind of regex mishap

Comment: This may be related to https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1398, which is an old issue, but the latest version has similar completion code. I did not attempt work-arounds to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the `zstyle` for matcher-list.

If you add the following to your `.zshrc`, it will fix it:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'e:|[._-]=* e:|=*' 'l:|=* e:|=*'
```

The `e:` (instead of the default `r:`) force the match to the end of the string.

The details for the options can be found in the [ZSH: Completion Matching Control docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Matching-Control)

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice where it put your cursor?  Since all files end with .R, it's automatically appending the possible suggestion for you.

The autocomplete is using "both ends" as described by Tshepang.

Try dropping a file into this folder without a .R name, and you'll see that .R bit go away.

Honestly, autocomplete actually needs something to "complete" not a blind directory assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Gert may well be right for the fix.  However, I suspect the reason for the incomplete nature of the list of files (breakdowns.R and eventloop.R) is due to those files being the only files in the current working directory that are marked as executable.  You can confirm this with an "ls -l" and look at the permissions for something like rwx.  If you do not have "./" or that directory explicitly in PATH then I would expect those two files not to appear either.

```
 8 -rwxr--r-- 1 userbob    groupbob      4420 May 28 15:55 filebob.R
```